# Is there an equivalent function in WinAPI to GLFW's glfwGetWindowUserPointer?

Tags: winapi, window, glfw

So I've created a window using WinAPI and I have a WindowProc callback function that handles window messages. In this function I want to access my own struct that wraps around the WinAPI `HWND`, to change other variables stored in this struct.

I know that GLFW supplies the functions `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` and `glfwGetWindowUserPointer` to fill this need. I tried searching for *GetWindowUserPointer*, *WindowUserPointer*, *WindowPointer* and *UserPointer* on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop, but found no results.

Is there any function or otherwise method to fill this need using WinAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`SetWindowLongPtr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) and [`GetWindowLongPtr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptrw)

The window creator always may use `GWLP_USERDATA`, you can store any data pointer of your choice.  If you reserve additional space (`cbWndExtra`) when registering the window class, you can store additional data at positive offsets as well.

A common technique is to use `WM_NCCREATE` to copy a pointer from the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindowEx` and copy it to the window data using `SetWindowLongPtr`.  Then other cases in the window procedure can retrieve the pointer and get your associated object.

Raymond Chen has [a complete explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140203-00/?p=1893) of using this feature to forward messages to a member function.

Comment: GWLP_USERDATA is for the code that called RegisterClass, not CreateWindow.

Comment: @Anders: Not true.  The code that calls `RegisterClass` is free to reserve space for its own use, via `cbWndExtra`.  `GWLP_USERDATA` is for the window creator.

Comment: You are incorrect sir. Most of the controls created by MS leave it unused (but not the SysLink control on NT5) but it is a storage slot reserved for the class implementor! "Note that this value, like the other window extra bytes and  the messages in the WM_USER range, belongs to the window class and not to the code that creates the window." https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050303-00/?p=36293

Comment: @Anders: As much respect as I have for Raymond, the official documentation (already linked in my answer) trumps what his blog says.  Official rule: "`GWLP_USERDATA` Sets the user data associated with the window. **This data is intended for use by the application that created the window.**"

Comment: It's not like MSDN is always correct. The statement is also unclear; are they talking about a window instance (CreateWindow) or the "inventor" (RegisterClass) of the window. I can point you to several classes both on Win32 and WinCE that use it for their own purpose so you cannot use it as your own storage if you are subclassing all the controls in a window etc. The name is unfortunate as well, USER in this case is user32, not the user(programmer) that calls CreateWindow.

Comment: @Anders: It takes an extreme level of denial to think that "the application that created the window" means "the OS library (user32) that registered standard window classes".  It's not at all unclear.

Comment: @Anders: Note that under your interpretation, it's also forbidden for SysLink to use `GWLP_USERDATA`, because SysLink is not registered by user32, but by comctl32. So trying to use the name to pin ownership to user32 is clearly wrong, as it contradicts both the formal documentation and practice.

Comment: "created the window" is the part that is unclear. You cannot call CreateWindow without you or Windows creating a window class for you. If MSDN said "created the HWND" or the "window instance" it would not be unclear.

Comment: The GWLP_USERDATA slot is a clearly a window manager thing, it is a part of the WND struct. Back in the day all MS controls lived in the user component (user.exe back then) along with the window manager (most of it is really in kernel mode but that is not important here). I'm not saying it is logical, it is just how it evolved. The effect of this is, whenever you see USER in a public API, it probably means the window implementer (and in rare cases, the window manager). No matter who is correct, the fact is that there are window implementations out there that use it for their own purpose.

Comment: A "user pointer" is a piece of data stored by the windowing framework (the term "window manager" means something else) for the convenience of the application.  This is true across a multitude of windowing frameworks (including ones mentioned right there in the question, but also ones that long predate the MS Windows windowing frameworks and influenced their design).  Your confusion stems from insisting that "window" actually means "window class", while the documentation keeps them separate.  "created a window" cannot mean `RegisterClass`, only `CreateWindow`.

Comment: In Windows, every function in user32 that takes/returns a HWND is part of the window manager. I don't care what other systems call things, we are talking about Windows. Again we can look at the history. Messages < WM_USER are fully understood and marshaled by the window manager. WM_USER...WM_APP-1 are for the window implementation and originally these all lived in user32/user for all windows provided by MS. WM_APP..."ATOM start"-1 are for the application.

Comment: @Anders really no unambiguous rule who is own of `GWLP_USERDATA` slot. [*I asked around and guidance is "unclear", though leaning slightly towards "it belongs to the person who called CreateWindow". For safety’s sake, then, you should just avoid it unless you can establish clear ownership.*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050303-00/?p=36293#comment-264143). if think - the variant application that created the window is more logical. but sometime class implementation also [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/LearnWin32/managing-application-state-) it.

Comment: @RbMm: The rule is unambiguous, problem is that some pervasive code didn't obey the rule.  For the purposes of this question, though, it is a distinction without merit, because the same coder writing the WndProc is also calling `CreateWindow`

Comment: @BenVoigt - i personally agree with you and also think that owner of  `GWLP_USERDATA` is code which call `CreateWindowEx`. but some 3-rd party windows classes implementations can break this rule

Comment: @BenVoigt - for example atl - [`AtlAxWinInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/d5f8cs41(v=vs.140)) - if look for implementation in *atlhost.h* - we can view that `AtlAxWindowProc` use `GWLP_USERDATA` . so for ATL's controls we can not use `GWLP_USERDATA`

Comment: MS programmers aren't perfect. Ben's interpretation makes sense, the other simply doesn't. However, this is just what you get if the documentation isn't *user-oriented* enough, like many low-level articles on MSDN, quite frankly, are. It should have said, in clear wording: If the *control author* needs extra data per-instance data, then use `cbWndExtra` and initialize that memory with `SetWindowLong[Ptr]` in `WM_CREATE` or `WM_NCCREATE`. If the *control user* needs extra per-instance data, use `..._USERDATA`. Besides, GWL[P]_USERDATA happens to be less typing, and is more prevalent on google.